# Passing multiple args into expanded if-else statements

Tags: python, oop, if-statement, args

I'm trying to pass multiple args. The first function creates the variables for age and gender. The second function redirects the arg based on gender. The 'num' variable should choose get_Male or get_Female and run through if-else statement until it finds equality. I'm new to python and it might be something simple. I just need to understand why the num variable doesn't pass. This is what I have so far...

```py
A_Age = 0
B_Age = 4
C_Age = 8
D_Age = 15
E_Age = 25
F_Age = 38
G_Age = 48
H_Age = 60

def main():
    #print('I am Rae...')
    with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
        gender = f.readline().split(":")[-1].strip()
        age = f.readline().split(":")[-1].strip().split('-')[0]
    print(gender) # Male
    print(age) # 25-32
    num = age
    gen = gender
    get_Gender(gen, num)

def get_Gender(gen, num):
    #print('I am Rza...')
    if gen == 'Male':
        print('The gender is male.')
        get_Male(gen, num)
    else:
        print('The gender is female.')
        get_Male(gen, num)
    return(gen, num)

def get_Male(gen, num):
    #print('I am Gza...')
    if gen == 'Male' and num == A_Age:
        print('Unintentional Injuries')
    elif num == B_Age:
        print('Neoplasms')
    elif num == C_Age:
        print('Teenage injuries')
    elif num == D_Age:
        print('School fights')
    elif num == E_Age:
        print('High Blood Pressure')
    elif num == F_Age:
        print('Hypertension')
    elif num == G_Age:
        print("Heart Disease")
    elif num == H_Age:
        print('old age')
        return  
    get_Female(gen, num)
    return(gen, num)                                            

def get_Female(gen, num):
    #print('I am meth...')
    if gen == 'Female' and num == A_Age:
        print('Unintentional Injuries')
    elif num == B_Age:
        print('Neoplasms')
    elif num == C_Age:
        print('Teenage injuries')
    elif num == D_Age:
        print('School fights')
    elif num == E_Age:
        print('High Blood Pressure')
    elif num == F_Age:
        print('Hypertension')
    elif num == G_Age:
        print("Heart Disease")
    elif num == H_Age:
       print('old age')
    return(gen, num)  

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can make this code more straightforward and readable, which make it easier to understand how your code works.

First, you don't need nested `if-else` statements. You can use `elif`, which only gets evaluated if the previous `if` or `elif` evaluated to `False`. NB: A [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) would simplify this function even further. I'll leave that up to you to discover.

Second, your functions `get_Male` and `get_Female` generally implement the same behavior, independent of the value of `gen`. Realizing this, we can consolidate these two functions into one and remove the `gen` parameter entirely.

Your functions `get_Male` and `get_Female` could look like this:

```
def print_symptom(num):  # Previously `get_Male` and `get_Female`
    if num == A_AGE:
        print('Unintentional Injuries')
    elif num == B_AGE:
        print('Neoplasms')
    elif num == C_AGE:
        print('Teenage injuries')
    elif num == D_AGE:
        print('School fights')
    elif num == E_AGE:
        print('High Blood Pressure')
    elif num == F_AGE:
        print('Hypertension')
    elif num == G_AGE:
        print("Heart Disease")
    elif num == H_AGE:
        print('old age')
```

You don't need to return `gen` and `num` since you don't use them anywhere else. The same goes for your `get_Gender` function (see next code block).

Since we removed the `gen` parameter from `print_symptoms`, we need to check that `gen` is either `'Male'` or `'Female'` in the function that will call `print_symptoms`:

```
def get_gender(gen, num):
    if gen == 'Male':
        print('The gender is male.')
    elif gen == 'Female':  # Previously checked in `get_Female`
        print('The gender is female.')
    else:
        print('Invalid gender. Exiting.')
        return

    print_symptom(gen, num)
```

Hopefully, these changes make it easier to understand what's going on in your code. Some other notes:

- Check out [this PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) which specifies naming conventions.
- In general, functions should be defined before other functions which call them. That way, when you read a file from top to bottom, you know what a function does before you encounter it within another function.

---

A cleaned-up version of your code could look like this:

```
A_AGE = 0
B_AGE = 4
C_AGE = 8
D_AGE = 15
E_AGE = 25
F_AGE = 38
G_AGE = 48
H_AGE = 60


def print_symptom(num):
    if num == A_AGE:
        print('Unintentional Injuries')
    elif num == B_AGE:
        print('Neoplasms')
    elif num == C_AGE:
        print('Teenage injuries')
    elif num == D_AGE:
        print('School fights')
    elif num == E_AGE:
        print('High Blood Pressure')
    elif num == F_AGE:
        print('Hypertension')
    elif num == G_AGE:
        print("Heart Disease")
    elif num == H_AGE:
        print('old age')


def get_gender(gen, num):
    if gen == 'Male':
        print('The gender is male.')
    elif gen == 'Female':
        print('The gender is female.')
    else:
        print('Invalid gender. Exiting.')
        return

    print_symptom(num)


def main():
    with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
        gender = f.readline().split(":")[-1].strip()
        age = f.readline().split(":")[-1].strip().split('-')[0]

    print(gender) # Male
    print(age) # 25-32

    get_gender(gender, age)


main()
```

Comment: This is so helpful. unfortunately, when I run the code the symptom doesn't print out. The variables are not constant as the age and gender can be different each run. Do I have to modify the variables in some way? I only ask because the information is being pulled from a textfile. gen is a string and num is an int.

Comment: I just noticed you give also the code written properly. I give you one point for this to be just. (but indentation is 4 characters not 3)

Comment: @KevinShane Glad to help :) The issue might be that `age` is actually a string, since you're reading it from a file (e.g., `"26"`). Try casting what you assign to `age` to an int like this: `age = int(f.readline().split(":")[-1].strip().split('-')[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

First, if I'm understanding your question correctly, the reason that your code isn't looking at both gender and age is because in `get_Gender()`, you check for gender but run `get_Male()` regardless of whether of what value you have for `gen`. The problem is specifically in this part:

```
def get_Gender(gen, num):
    #print('I am Rza...')
    if gen == 'Male':
        print('The gender is male.')
        get_Male(gen, num)
    else:
        print('The gender is female.')

        get_Male(gen, num)    #<---- I think this should be get_Female()

    return(gen, num)
```

Another change that will make it easier to troubleshoot code like this: don't nest a bunch of if else statements like that. Instead, you can use "elif", which will only run if the prior if-statement resolved to False. Here is an example of how you can update your code:

```
def get_Male(gen, num):
    if gen == 'Male' and num == A_Age:
        print('Unintentional Injuries')
    elif  num == B_Age:
        print('Neoplasms')
    elif num == C_Age:
        print('Teenage injuries')
    elif num == D_Age:
        print('School fights')
    elif num == E_Age:
        print('High Blood Pressure')
    elif num == F_Age:
        print('Hypertension')
    elif num == G_Age:
        print("Heart Disease")
    elif num == H_Age:
        print('old age')

    return(gen, num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. You can use the sentence `elif` instead of `else` and then `if`
2. You can use a dictionary to perform a kind of switch operation of other languages. I'd do something as follows:

```
switch = {
    0: 'Unintentional Injuries',
    4: 'Neoplasms',
    8: 'Teenage injuries',
    15: 'School fights',
    25: 'High Blood Pressure',
    38: 'Hypertension',
    48: 'Heart Disease'.
    60: 'old age'    
}

disease = switch[num]
print(disease)
```